# Failing to fill multiple rows in Pandas Dataframe with .iloc() method

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, datetime

I'm having a hard time adding multiple rows of data to a dataset I have. For some reason, when I try to add values, it only sets the first row, and the rest of the rows are set to NaN.

It outputs the following as the head:

```
         Time    Open Tone
0  1449341520  377.48    0
1  1449341580  377.50  NaN
2  1449341640  377.50  NaN
3  1449341760  377.50  NaN
4  1449341820  377.50  NaN
```

Expected:

```
         Time    Open Tone
0  1449341520  377.48    0
1  1449341580  377.50    0
2  1449341640  377.50    0
3  1449341760  377.50    0
4  1449341820  377.50    0
```

`btc_data.iloc[:position, -1] = to_btc_data["tone_id"]` is supposed to set those rows up to what `position` is, but instead it only sets the first row.

Full code:

```
from pygooglenews import GoogleNews
import datetime
import time
from datetime import timezone
from datetime import datetime
import json
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

gn = GoogleNews()

def create_week_data(ts=1449341520):
  df = pd.DataFrame()

  search = gn.search('Bitcoin', from_=datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), to_=datetime.fromtimestamp(ts+604800).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))

  titles=[]
  dates=[]
  timestamps=[]

  for item in search["entries"]:
    titles.append(item["title"])
    dates.append(item["published"])

  df["published"] = dates
  df["title"] = titles

  for item in dates:
    month = 1

    if (item[8:11] == "Jan"):
      month = 1
    elif (item[8:11] == "Feb"):
      month = 2
    elif (item[8:11] == "Mar"):
      month = 3
    elif (item[8:11] == "Apr"):
      month = 4
    elif (item[8:11] == "May"):
      month = 5
    elif (item[8:11] == "Jun"):
      month = 6
    elif (item[8:11] == "Jul"):
      month = 7
    elif (item[8:11] == "Aug"):
      month = 8
    elif (item[8:11] == "Sep"):
      month = 9
    elif (item[8:11] == "Oct"):
      month = 10
    elif (item[8:11] == "Nov"):
      month = 11
    elif (item[8:11] == "Dec"):
      month = 12

    dt = item[5:7]+"/"+str(month)+"/"+item[12:16]

    timestamps.append(int(time.mktime(datetime.strptime(dt, "%d/%m/%Y").timetuple())))


  df["timestamp"] = timestamps

  return df

from ibm_watson import ToneAnalyzerV3
from ibm_cloud_sdk_core.authenticators import IAMAuthenticator 
import json

watson_api_key = "KEY"
watson_url = "URL"

authenticator = IAMAuthenticator(watson_api_key)
tone_analyzer = ToneAnalyzerV3(version='2021-11-27', authenticator=authenticator)
tone_analyzer.set_service_url(watson_url)

def to_tone(df = df):
  toneData = pd.DataFrame()
  tones = []
  timestamps = []

  for index, row in df.iterrows():
    timestamp = row["timestamp"]
    title = row["title"]

    dump = json.dumps(tone_analyzer.tone(title).get_result())[10:]
    tone_id = 0;

    if (dump.find("Joy") >= 0):
      tone_id = 1
    elif (dump.find("Anger") >= 0):
      tone_id = 2
    elif (dump.find("Fear") >= 0):
      tone_id = 3
    elif (dump.find("Sadness") >= 0):
      tone_id = 4
    elif (dump.find("Analytical") >= 0):
      next
    elif (dump.find("Confident") >= 0):
      next
    elif (dump.find("Tentative") >= 0):
      next
    else:
      tone_id = 0

    tones.append(tone_id)
    timestamps.append(timestamp)

    if (len(tones) >= 1):
      break

  toneData["timestamp"] = timestamps
  toneData["tone_id"] = tones


  return toneData

print(to_tone())

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.set_printoptions(precision=15, suppress=True)
btc_data = pd.read_csv(
    "/content/drive/MyDrive/Science Fair/output.csv",
    names=["Time", "Open"])

btc_data["Tone"] = None

ts = 1449341520
position = 0

while (True):
  to_btc_data = pd.DataFrame()

  to_btc_data = to_tone(df=create_week_data(ts=ts))

  for index, row in btc_data.iterrows():
    timestamp = row["Time"]

    if (timestamp >= ts):
      ts = timestamp
      position = index
      break

  btc_data.iloc[:position, -1] = to_btc_data["tone_id"]

  ts+=604800

  print(btc_data.head())

  if (ts > 1617148800):
    btc_data.iloc[ts+604800:] = to_btc_data[0]
    break

btc_data.head()
```

Whatever value is in the `to_btc_data` DF is supposed to be set there. What am I doing wrong here?

Also sorry about the terribly structured code. I am playing on organizing it during production, and I usually don't code in Python so I won't be writing any beautiful code.

Comment: Where you have `next`, you need to have `continue`.  That's not what `next` is for.

Comment: `len(tones)` will always be >= 1,  You just added `tone_id` to it.

Comment: I'm aware. I will probably be removing a part of the code since I really don't need the tones to be in a dataframe.

Comment: You are not incrementing your `position` variable inside `while` loop. No matter how many time `while` loop executes it is always set to `zero`.

Comment: I fixed that a few minutes ago. Thanks for pointing that out.